# How to search through GitHub repo for particular directories and files

Tags: jekyll

I am building a Jekyll blogging platform for GitHub pages[enter link description here](https://github.com/singh1114/thejekyllproject). Now I want to allow the people who already have a Jekyll blog to make use of the CMS. I will list all the repositories under the registered user. The user will click on one of the Repository.

Now, there are two options, either I can clone the repository and make the checks in the local which is time-consuming, on the other hand, I can make a search through the repo using beautifulsoup or any other library.

Which of the following options should I use? And are there any better option than the ones that I described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github has a REST API that you can use:
https://developer.github.com/v3/

I am not completely sure, but for the use case of listing files, this seems like a good starting Point: 
https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the quick reply.